# Null field must not be display...!

Tags: android, null

I am developing map application,
In my app I display full address 
But I have just one problem.
if address field not get any data then that field will not displayed.
How can I fix this?
necessary code is bellow
ActivityMain.java

```
String zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea(); 
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

//              if (city.trim().isEmpty()) {
//                  
//              } else if (state.trim().isEmpty()) {
//                  
//              } else if (zip.trim().isEmpty()) {
//                  
//              } else if (country.trim().isEmpty()) {
//                  
//              } else {
//
//              }

                String title = zip + "," + city + "," + state + "," + country;
                showPosition.setText(zip + "\n" + city + "\n" + state + "\n" + country);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).title(title));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showPosition is the TextView?
You should set the "visibility" attribute (showPosition.setVisibility(View.GONE or INVISIBLE).

You should reformat the string which will be displayed in the TextView.

```
String title = "";
if(zip != null && zip.trim().length()>0) {
   title += zip + "\n"
}

// Same for the other fields (without else)
if(country != null && country.trim().length()>0) {
   title += country + "\n"
}
```

Comment: No no.. if any from zip , city,state and country is empty then that field must not display. other field must be display.. ex. if zip = null then zip code must not be display. other 3 field display..

Comment: So, when you write "zip + "," + city + "," + state + "," + country;", if a variable is null => the result will be NULL.
You should reformat the text which will be displayed in the textview.
String title = (zip == null?"": zip) + etc..

Comment: Not Working.. Got Error

Answer (score 0):

try this
String title = ""+zip + "," + city + "," + state + "," + country;
                    showPosition.setText(""+zip + "\n" + city + "\n" + state + "\n" + country);